# Calabash-android : rake build error

Tags: android, ruby, rubygems, calabash

I am new to calabash-android , i am getting the following error while executing "rake build " command .

C:\calabash-android\ruby-gem>rake build

rake aborted!

cannot load such file -- C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/popen4-0.1.2/lib/op
en3
lib/calabash-android/helpers.rb:6:in `'

C:/calabash-android/ruby-gem/Rakefile:2:in `load'

C:/calabash-android/ruby-gem/Rakefile:2:in `'

(See full trace by running task with --trace)

These are the steps i have followed

git clone https://github.com/calabash/calabash-android.git

git submodule init

git submodule update

i used gem install popen4
but i again same error
Please help me .

Answer (score 1):

Run the same command, adding `--trace` at the end, and then post the results, so we have more information available for debugging.

Also, have you tried `gem update --system` and then `gem update popen4`? This might solve any issues with the gem.

Comment: Thanks for the reply its working fine with ur suggestion . Thank You

Comment: If it was helpful, please consider [accepting the answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) as it helps the community know which questions are unresolved and helps you build reputation =)

Answer (score 0):

Why are you trying to build the calabash-android gem itself?

If you don't intend to modify it internally, just install it via `gem install calabash-android` and you're good to go!

Comment: Hi Felipe,

just i want to add some customized steps using java so we need to build entire project after adding the code using "rake build" command hear is the link that explains the procedure .

http://fangmobile.com/2013/03/04/four-levels-of-customization-in-calabash-android/